# Windows Store App running .msi installer

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, store

I am developing a windows store app which downloads a MSI file from a URL.
I want to automatically run the MSI installer from C# code.

1. first problem is the windows smart screen - the MSI is not signed
2. event when smart screen is disabled

   ```
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
   returns false;
   ```

file = downloaded .msi installer

Any ideas?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: store app run in a sandbox and I doubt that you can run a MSI from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to launch an MSI (or other executable formats) directly from a Windows Store app. This is specifically called out in the remarks in the [LaunchFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701471.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation.