# Run the MSI file in the UWP application

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have an UWP application, In that I need to run the MSI file on the button click.
I don't think UWP will support "process.start(filename)". Is it possible in UWP to achieve this?.

Answer (score 0):

The UWP cant open MSI.

But uwp can open the other type file.

You can use Launcher.

1. Pick the msi that you want run.
2. Run msi by launcher file.
3. The result is always failed.

   ```
   private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       //pick msi file
       FileOpenPicker pick = new FileOpenPicker();
       pick.FileTypeFilter.Add(".msi");
       StorageFile file = await pick.PickSingleFileAsync();
       //run
       bool result = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
       if (result)
       {
           //success
       }
   }
   ```

But you will see the result is false ,because `Many file types that contain executable code, for example .exe, .msi, and .js files, are blocked from launching`

You can open the folder and make the use to click the msi file.The code is:

```
    private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //pick msi file
        var pick = new FileOpenPicker();
        pick.FileTypeFilter.Add(".msi");
        var file = await pick.PickSingleFileAsync();
        //run
        var result = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, new LauncherOptions
        {
            TreatAsUntrusted = true,
            DisplayApplicationPicker = true
        });
        if (result)
        {
            //success
        }
        else
        {
            //alway failed
            var folder = await file.GetParentAsync();
            if (folder != null)
            {
                await Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(
                    folder, //if you can get the file's parent
                    new FolderLauncherOptions
                    {
                        ItemsToSelect = {file}
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

See:[Windows Store App running .msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771306/windows-store-app-running-msi-installer)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701471.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396